# 2017 CF MY17 Black Edition - "Routine Maintenance Required"

Tags: engine, maintenance, mitsubishi, service, lancer

My 2017 Black Edition Lancer shows this alert every time I start the car. It's been doing this for a few days now. The *service sticker* says next service at **17,000km**; I'm only halfway there.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Take it in and get it checked - mainenance is on time **or** mileage.